# How to add the class name from `*ngFor` loop?

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor

I would like to add the variable value as `class` name in the iterator. How to do that?

Here is my code :

```
<ul class="cart-card">
    <li *ngFor="let size of sizes" class="cart-card--content" 
    [ngClass]="{'active': activeSize == size, ['size'] : size }"> //notworks
      <div class="cc-content-desc">{{size}}</div>
      <div class="cc-content-image-xs"></div>
      <div class="cc-content-desc1">L+W+H=36</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I am trying if there is a size in the loop, add the `size` as the class name. But it doesn't work. How to add data itself as a class name with existing class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to set the class to `size` value whenever the option is active, 
use ternary operator. ngClass can be set to en empty string too. Using this [reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#usage-notes), here is a suggestion:

**HTML**

```
...
<li (click)="activeSize=size" *ngFor="let size of sizes" class="cart-card--content"
  [ngClass]=" activeSize === size ? size :''"> 
...
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqqpcv)

Answer (score 3):

Try this out. [class] = "size" will set the value of size as class name.

```
<ul class="cart-card">
    <li *ngFor="let size of sizes" class="cart-card--content" [class]= "size"
    [ngClass]="{'active': activeSize == size"> //now works
      <div class="cc-content-desc">{{size}}</div>
      <div class="cc-content-image-xs"></div>
      <div class="cc-content-desc1">L+W+H=36</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```